# Protection against SQL injection

Tags: php, security, sql-injection

Does the following PHP MySQL statement protect against SQL Injection?

```
$strSQL = "SELECT * FROM Benutzer WHERE Benutzername = '".$Benutzer."' AND Password = '".md5($PW)."'";
```

The Variables `$Benutzer` and `$PW` are inputs from the User.

We're checking the username and password against common SQL Injection techniques:

> `' or 0=0 --`, `" or 0=0 --`, `or 0=0
>   --`, `' or 0=0 #`, `" or 0=0 #`, `or 0=0 #`, `' or 'x'='x`, `" or "x"="x`,
>   `') or ('x'='x`, `' or 1=1--`, `" or
>   1=1--`, `or 1=1--`, `' or a=a--`, `"
>   or "a"="a`, `') or ('a'='a`, `") or
>   ("a"="a`, `hi" or "a"="a`, `hi" or 1=1
>   --`, `hi' or 1=1 --`, `hi' or 'a'='a`, `hi') or ('a'='a` and `hi") or
>   ("a"="a`.

Am I missing something? Should I use a different method to protect against SQL injection?

Comment: where are those variables coming from? you mention skipping login so does this mean those variables are coming from a cookie?

Comment: the variables are coming from a $_POST and will be sent to a function. After a successful login we write a Session-Var. With skipping i mean to login without a valid password. - by the way - thanks for so many quick replies.

Comment: If you ever see SQL being produced by appending strings together, loud alarm bells should go off. Always, always use bound parameters, if available. See PDO and MySQLi libraries in PHP.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You may want to look into parameterized queries for querying the database.  This eliminates SQL injection attacks.

I work primarily with postgreSQL, and the format for doing such a query would look something like this:

```
$query = 'select * from Benutzer where Benutzername = $1 and Passwort = $2';
$params = array($Benutzer, md5($PW));
$results = pg_query_params($query, $params);
```

Most databases have a function that will be similar to this funationality.

I hope this helps and good luck!

Kyle

Comment: PDO works like this. see http://fr2.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php

Answer (score 5):

I'd personally advise using an algorithm such as SHA1 over MD5, as there is a lower possibility of collisions. You should be [salting your passwords](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29) too, otherwise one can use [rainbow tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table) to crack your passwords.

Also, use [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](http://au.php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) to escape things, don't simply do a search and replace for common injections.

Comment: No, do *not* use string escaping. String escaping is very easy to do wrong, and hard to do right. Use bound parameters. Bound parameters are sent to the database through alternate channels, and so cannot possibly be parsed as SQL.

Comment: `mysql_real_escape_string()` is executed by the MySQL server, and I believe the MySQL guys know a thing or two about getting that stuff right.

Comment: Or, rather, the MySQL library in PHP, which is made by the MySQL team, IIRC.

Comment: thank you all - we will add a little bit of salt to the password and use the mysql_real_escape_string() to protect the user inputs we used in our sql-statements.

Comment: @Ryan McCue: you'd hope so, but not really. mysql_real_escape_string() exists because its predecessor mysql_escape_string was horribly broken. And anyway it's still a flawed methodology.

Comment: MySQL string literal escaping isn't hard to do right, it's just easy to forget to do, which is why parameterised queries are a good thing. But Ryan is correct that escaping is the right concept (whether explicitly or via parameters), whilst trying to sniff for “bad” strings that “might” be signs of an injection attempt is totally the wrong thing: laughably incomplete, whilst also blocking some valid input.

Answer (score 5):

[Prepared](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) [statements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) are a fantastic invention.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php and http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php for examples.

Answer (score 2):

If security is supposed to be as high as possible, you ought to use some other hashing method than md5 - like e.g. sha256. Also, use a password salt.

Comment: He is asking about SQL injection.

Comment: Yes, and that part was already answered. He also said that he wants high security - so I gave him some extra tips, free of charge.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `mysql_real_escape_string()`

```
$strSQL = "SELECT * 
        FROM Benutzer 
        WHERE Benutzername = '".mysql_real_escape_string($Benutzer)."' 
        AND Passwort = '".mysql_real_escape_string(md5($PW))."'";
```

Make sure that when users register, you register using the same technique .. for example,

```
AND Passwort = '".mysql_real_escape_string(md5($PW))."'"
```

and

```
AND Passwort = '".md5(mysql_real_escape_string($PW))."'"
```

may produce different results depending upon the input text.

And yes, also add some "salt" to this password as well. For some ideas you do like this

sha1(md5($pass)):
  sha1($salt.$pass):
  sha1($pass.$salt):
  sha1($username.$pass):
  sha1($username.$pass.$salt):

Comment: There is no need to escape the password with `mysql_real_escape_string()`, since MD5s are hexadecimal numbers, and will not contain anything but the characters 0-9 or A-F.

Comment: No, do not use string escaping. Use bound parameters.

Comment: There may be no need to escape in that particular case, but it's a good habit to get into to use the escaping on *every* string if you're going to be using string-building. Separation of concerns: it's not the job of your query builder to know what are valid characters in an MD5 digest, and maybe in the future someone will swap the md5 call for something else that can include characters you do need to worry about.

Answer (score 0):

> The security standards should be as high as possible.

If md5 got included in your design with nobody raising an eyebrow or spitting coffee on themselves, then you need to revisit the security issue with the client.  If security is that critical they need to spring for a security specialist to join your team.  Everybody says they want secure code.  Few are willing to pay for it, so few actually get it.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to strip_tags any public content (or use your own html filter) to prevent XSS as well.

Comment: htmlspecialchars() during the output phase is the correct thing to do to prevent XSS.

Comment: Unless you want to display some user generated html...